# i want to send a mail to the currently logged in user when the invoice status is updated/changed how can i do it?

Tags: php, laravel

here is my Invoice Status update form

**index.blade.php**

```
<td>
    <form action="{{url('/invoice_status_upadated')}}" method="POST">
        <input class="form-control" name="id" type="hidden" value="{{$inv['id']}}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="status">
                <option value="0" {{$inv->status == 0 ? 'selected':''}}>Pending </option>
                <option value="1" {{$inv->status == 1 ? 'selected':''}}>In Process </option>
                <option value="2" {{$inv->status == 2 ? 'selected':''}}>Completed </option>
                <option value="3" {{$inv->status == 3 ? 'selected':''}}>Cancelled </option>
            </select>
        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-outline-success">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</td>
```

**web.php:**

```
Route::post('/invoice_status_upadated', 'App\Http\Controllers\TemplateController@invoice_status_upadated',)->name('invoice_status_upadated');
```

**TemplateController**

```
public function invoice_status_upadated(Request $request){ 
    $data= Invoice::find($request->id);
    $data->status = $request->status;
    $data->save();
    return redirect('invoices');
}
```

Now i want to send an email to currently logged in user

Comment: Where are you stuck then exactly? Done any research? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail

Comment: What **exactly** is your question about this? Sending the mail? Determining the currently logged in user? Determining whether the status has changed?

Comment: my basic question was how can i send the email when the status is changed ... i sorted it out thank you so much for your concerns

Comment: Even that is two questions, potentially, or two aspects - determining the status and sending the email. Again, unclear where you were stuck or how you were stuck. We need a precise problem to solve, not just a "do the design and write the code for me" request.

Answer (score -2):

Here is what i would do :

```
   if ($data->status !== $request->status) {
      // Here you can send your email, and set the new status.
      $data->status = $request->status;
    }
```

You have to check if the status isn't the same, then if it changed, you can put the code you want. First, set the new status, then you can send the email.

Here you can found how to create the mail template and send it :
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail

Comment: Please share more details. The given code does not send out any mail

Comment: He never asked "how to send a mail".

Comment: Didn't he? The question contains the text "i want to send an email to currently logged in user", so does the title of the question

Comment: "when the invoice status is changed", this is the currently problem.

Comment: How did you identify that?